# ModelMapper immutable DTO custom mapping

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have an immutable DTO with all fields `final`, having only getters and no setters.

How can I use **ModelMapper** to add custom mapping from my entity to this DTO?

[Documentation](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#providers) shows usage with mapping getters to setters, but my DTO has no setters because it is immutable...

I'm trying to use *ModelMapper* to auto copy bulk of fields and customize a few myself, thus preventing using a n-arg DTO constructor.